# How to convert from .NET Framework datetime type in synapse pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am developing a pipeline in Azure Synapse to convert a `jason` file downloaded via api call into a parquet.
The column names are `lastModDate` and `lastModifiedDate` and I want to store these in the sink as Datetime or `DatetimeOffset` type, but I got an error. I think the datetime format is type of .NET Framework, and want to convert it to format like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:dd`. The data is converted correctly in the data preview, but what should I do in the copy activity?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to transform the data before copying to destination data store, the ideal way is to use a mapping data flow activity and use derive column transformation to convert the source data as per your sink data store requirement.

Copy activity is only for data movement between data stores and not to transform the data.

For more info, please refer to this document: [Derived column transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column)